# where do certs get installed?

Tags: 12.10, certificates

I just installed a cert from my company.  It was on a usb key and i double clicked the file... inputted the password it asked for and it seems to have imported properly. 
now i'm trying to configure my wifi settings so that I use that cert when connecting to my firm's wifi network.  I'm being asked to specify the location of the cert but i don't know where it is.

i checked /etc/ssl/cert but i can't find it.

One thing i've noticed is that in the "Choose a certificate authority certificate" dialog box that appears, by default, it looks like it's looking for *.der,*.pem,*.crt,*.cer.
But my cert has a .pfx extension.

any help would be appreciated. 
thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will find all installed certs in `/etc/ssl/certs` or below. Either the cert is really there or you find a link pointing to the place (most likely under `/usr/share/ca-certificates`)